# Wolfram Mathematica Code please

Tags: scripting, homework, wolfram-alpha-queries, mathematica-online

Consider two natural numbers of two-digits, like 46 and 96. They have the property that by exchanging the place of their digits and multiplying the so obtained numbers, we get the same product; i.e.,

```
46 96 == 64 69
```

> (* True *)

a. [4 points] How many pairs of two-digit natural numbers have this property?

b. [2 points] How many pairs so multiplied result in four different digits?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica stack exchange!  You'll find that "write this code for me" questions are not very well-received here, as this site is not a tutoring or homework-answering service.  Instead, if you explain what you've tried, what you know about Mathematica, and where you're running into difficulties --- ideally with some *specific* questions about how to implement this in Mathematica or how the code works --- then we can help.  please take the tour and consult Meta for how to ask good questions!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The answer to (a) can be determined by brute force with little difficulty.  (There are only about 10000 possibilities, and everyone can be tested quickly.)  After that, simple examination of the products yields the answer to {b}.

Answer (score 3):

You can use brute force like this for (a)

```
data = Range[11, 99];
result = First@Last@Reap@Do[
      d = IntegerDigits[data[[n]]];
      n1 = d[[1]];
      n2 = d[[2]];
      Do[
       d = IntegerDigits[data[[m]]];
       m1 = d[[1]];
       m2 = d[[2]];
       If[(n1 + n2*10)*(m1 + m2*10) == (n2 + n1*10)*(m2 + m1*10),
        Sow[{n1 + n2*10, m1 + m2*10}]
        ]
       ,
       {m, 1, Length[data]}
       ],
      {n, 1, Length[data]}
      ];

Length[result]
(* 209 *)
```

Which gives

```
result

{{11, 11}, {11, 22}, {11, 33}, {11, 44}, {11, 55}, {11, 66}, {11, 
  77}, {11, 88}, {11, 99}, {21, 12}, {21, 24}, {21, 36}, {21, 
  48}, {31, 13}, {31, 26}, {31, 39}, {41, 14}, {41, 28}, {51, 
  15}, {61, 16}, {71, 17}, {81, 18}, {91, 19}, {12, 21}, {12, 
  42}, {12, 63}, {12, 84}, {22, 11}, {22, 22}, {22, 33}, {22, 
  44}, {22, 55}, {22, 66}, {22, 77}, {22, 88}, {22, 99}, {32, 
  23}, {32, 46}, {32, 69}, {42, 12}, {42, 24}, {42, 36}, {42, 
  48}, {52, 25}, {62, 13}, {62, 26}, {62, 39}, {72, 27}, {82, 
  14}, {82, 28}, {92, 29}, {13, 31}, {13, 62}, {13, 93}, {23, 
  32}, {23, 64}, {23, 96}, {33, 11}, {33, 22}, {33, 33}, {33, 
  44}, {33, 55}, {33, 66}, {33, 77}, {33, 88}, {33, 99}, {43, 
  34}, {43, 68}, {53, 35}, {63, 12}, {63, 24}, {63, 36}, {63, 
  48}, {73, 37}, {83, 38}, {93, 13}, {93, 26}, {93, 39}, {14, 
  41}, {14, 82}, {24, 21}, {24, 42}, {24, 63}, {24, 84}, {34, 
  43}, {34, 86}, {44, 11}, {44, 22}, {44, 33}, {44, 44}, {44, 
  55}, {44, 66}, {44, 77}, {44, 88}, {44, 99}, {54, 45}, {64, 
  23}, {64, 46}, {64, 69}, {74, 47}, {84, 12}, {84, 24}, {84, 
  36}, {84, 48}, {94, 49}, {15, 51}, {25, 52}, {35, 53}, {45, 
  54}, {55, 11}, {55, 22}, {55, 33}, {55, 44}, {55, 55}, {55, 
  66}, {55, 77}, {55, 88}, {55, 99}, {65, 56}, {75, 57}, {85, 
  58}, {95, 59}, {16, 61}, {26, 31}, {26, 62}, {26, 93}, {36, 
  21}, {36, 42}, {36, 63}, {36, 84}, {46, 32}, {46, 64}, {46, 
  96}, {56, 65}, {66, 11}, {66, 22}, {66, 33}, {66, 44}, {66, 
  55}, {66, 66}, {66, 77}, {66, 88}, {66, 99}, {76, 67}, {86, 
  34}, {86, 68}, {96, 23}, {96, 46}, {96, 69}, {17, 71}, {27, 
  72}, {37, 73}, {47, 74}, {57, 75}, {67, 76}, {77, 11}, {77, 
  22}, {77, 33}, {77, 44}, {77, 55}, {77, 66}, {77, 77}, {77, 
  88}, {77, 99}, {87, 78}, {97, 79}, {18, 81}, {28, 41}, {28, 
  82}, {38, 83}, {48, 21}, {48, 42}, {48, 63}, {48, 84}, {58, 
  85}, {68, 43}, {68, 86}, {78, 87}, {88, 11}, {88, 22}, {88, 
  33}, {88, 44}, {88, 55}, {88, 66}, {88, 77}, {88, 88}, {88, 
  99}, {98, 89}, {19, 91}, {29, 92}, {39, 31}, {39, 62}, {39, 
  93}, {49, 94}, {59, 95}, {69, 32}, {69, 64}, {69, 96}, {79, 
  97}, {89, 98}, {99, 11}, {99, 22}, {99, 33}, {99, 44}, {99, 
  55}, {99, 66}, {99, 77}, {99, 88}, {99, 99}}
```

If you want to eliminate the `{nn, mm}` pairs, which will always be true, such as {99,77} then it will reduce the size ofcourse. This can be done by an extra `If`.

Your `{46, 96}` is in there.  Part b can now be solved easily from the above list by multiplying each result and finding if the result has 4 different digits or not.

Comment: is the downvote because I answered what looks like a HW question or is it because something wrong with my answer so I know in order to  fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that reverses a number

`rev[x_]:=FromDigits@Reverse@IntegerDigits@x`

Here's an interesting way to filter results once you get them.

If we know that a list of numbers `{a,b}` has `a b==rev@a rev@b`, we don't really care that `{rev@a,rev@b}` has that property, or the reverse of that list.  So if your result is `list`, you can do

```
list//.{a___,{x_,y_},b___,OrderlessPatternSequence@{z_,w_},c___}/;
      {x,y}=={rev@z,rev@w}:>{a,{x,y},b,c}
```

to remove some obvious terms.  This is computationally expensive, but conceptually simple.  I'm replacing instances of stuff which includes pairs `{x,y}` and `{z,w}` for which `x==rev@z` and `y==rev@w` with just the stuff with `{x,y}` and not `{z,w}`.

- `//.`, `ReplaceRepeated` does the replacing
- `a___`, `b___`, `c___` each mean 'stuff', `BlankNullSequence`
- `{x_,y_}` and `OrderlessPatternSequence@{z_,w_}` mean pairs, and they're spliced between `a,b,c` with any amount of elements in between or before or after, and it could be `{w,z}` instead of `{z,w}`
- `/;`, `Condition` is the 'such that'
- Finally, the `:>` is `RuleDelayed`, used by `//.` to substitute in a new list with `{z,w}` absent.

Other obvious cases for `{x,y}` are when `x` has `x==rev@x` or `x==rev@y` or when there's divisibility, so you can do these simpler rules only once (with `/.` instead of `//.`) like so

```
list/.OrderlessPatternSequence@{x_,y_}/;
    Or[x==rev@x,x==rev@y,Divisible[rev@x,y]]->Nothing//.
    {a___,{x_,y_},b___,OrderlessPatternSequence@{z_,w_},c___}/;
  {x,y}=={rev@z,rev@w}:>{a,{x,y},b,c}
```

Doing this with `list` the full 10000 guys results in a fairly minimal set of pairs, which have GCDs ranging from 1 to 12.